# How secure is it to implement most of the applications functionality using WASM on the client side/ in the browser?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, web-service, web-assembly

I understand that nothing is perfectly secured.

If we have a web app where most of the functionality is done inside the browser using WASM, can someone get the binary of that WASM and use most of its functionality?

What do we need to pay attention to regarding security when writing a WASM web app?

Edited with my intent of the question in the first place. I should have make the question more clear.

What about intellectual property for the codes write the program? ( Sorry, this should be my intent of my question)

Comment: *"What about intellectual property for the codes"* - intellectual property is a legal construct and off-topic here. To stay on-topic please be more clear on what you imagine behind this legal construct in terms of information security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone get the binary of that wasm and use most functionality?

Yes, the WASM itself is not protected. The security model of WASM is not about who can use the WASM binary but what the binary can do independent from who is executing it. This is achieved by executing the binary a restrictive execution environment (sandbox).

> What do we need to pay attention to regarding security when writing a WASM web app?

The security aspects are similar to existing web applications done using Javascript.

The server has no actual control over the execution of the client side code, i.e. it has no control over the execution environment nor can it guarantee that the original server provided code is running. Thus anything coming from the client must be sanity checked.

The code is also not protected against inspection by others, so any secrets inside the code are not protected. This means both plain secrets like access token, but also algorithms since it is possible to get the binary and reverse engineer it. Similar to other code running on the client side obfuscation can be used to make reverse engineering harder but it does not make it impossible.

Comment: Yes.  agree that  WASM security  for the is achieved by providing a restrictive execution environment (sandbox). for the client. 
What about intellectual property for the codes write the program? ( Sorry, this should be my intent of my question)

Comment: @user95432: Intellectual property is a purely legal construct. If you mean protection against reverse engineering - it doesn't have any. See updated answer.